Using IF Statement with COUNTIFS and also checking if cell is blank in COUNTIFS
I have a quick formula question I can't seem to figure out. I have two worksheets with the following names. One is 'BY Load', the other is 'Inventory Check'. I have a list of numbers (loadnum) on the 'BY Load' in column F. I have the same item number list (Could be in a different order) (This column name on this sheet is LICENSE_PLATE) on the 'Inventory Check' worksheet in column A. I also have a mandate column on worksheet 'BY Load' in column AC and a MFG_DATE column on sheet 'Inventory Check' in column K. Within these sheets I'm looking to see if the mfg date matches for the items.
The below formula works and returns "Yes" if the mfg date matches the item #, "No" if they don't.
=IF(COUNTIFS('BY Load'!F:F,A2, 'BY Load'!AC:AC,K2)>0,"Yes","No")
The part I can't figure out is what if the cells for mandate and MFG_DATE on both are blank? The formula I used will report as "No" since it's not greater than 0. The issue is both cells are blank so if they are both blank I want it to report "Yes" since they match. I want "Yes" if the cells for mandate and MFG_DATE match even if they are empty.
I've tried placing an ISBLANK in multiple areas of the formula with no luck. What would be the best way to do this. I'm sure it's simple and I'm just overthinking it.
BY Load Worksheet

loadnum (F) Data in Cell = 6727599
mandate (AC) Cell is blank

Inventory Check Worksheet

LICENCE_PLATE (A) Data in Cell = 6727599
MFG_DATE (K) Cell is blank

Here's a link to the sample data.
Sample Excel Data File

Post few of sample data to your post.

I just added a sample data file to the post.

1 row of (too) many columns per sheet is not a reproducable sample also will linking to a file rather than posting samples as data ( https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables ) not help any future visitors to this site experiencing a similar problem.

I'm not 100% sure if I understand what you want, but maybe try this =IF(COUNTIFS('BY Load'!F:F,A2, 'BY Load'!AC:AC,IF(K2="";"";K2))>0,"Yes","No")

This worked. Thank You
